# How to take screenshots of sections of the screen?

Tags: gnome, compiz, screenshot

On Mac OS X, there is a handy key combo for taking a screenshot of any arbitrary rectangle section of the screen(Command-Shift-4).

Is there something similar(maybe Compiz plugin) for Ubuntu/Gnome?

Comment: Ahja's answer should be the accepted one

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Shutter](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/shutter) is a good screenshot tool that has this feature, among others.

Comment: it's slow ... 5CM better

Comment: Use `Shift` + `PrintScreen` (see [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15624/how-to-take-screenshots-of-sections-of-the-screen#334874) below).

Comment: @AlexanderPozdneev Shift+PrintScreen make the sound of screenshot capture but the screenshot is not copied into the clipboard

Comment: Another very good libre software for screenshot is Flameshot, available in Ubuntu repositories

Answer (score 108):

Press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>printScr</kbd> and then a click drag to select the area you want a screen shot of

***It is possible that the key combination <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrntScreen</kbd> may not be the short cut to do this, then -***

1. Open System Settings (also known as gnome-control-center)
2. Go to Keyboard
3. Click the shortcuts tab
4. Click on screen shots
5. Click on the key combination corresponding to "take a screenshot of an area"
6. Press the desired keycombination ( such as shift + printScreen )
7. use the key combination, your cursor arrow turns to a '+' like sign.
8. click and drag to select the area you want a screen shot of.

**Command line interface way( i.e through terminal)**(you need dconf-editor for this) -

1. open terminal using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. enter `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot` to get the key combination currently assigned to get a screen shot of an area.
3. If you want to change it enter`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot "[<Shift>Print']"`
   Simly replace `"[<Shift>Print']"` with your desired key combination.

[This is a link to ubuntu wiki about keybindings and is handy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings)

**Note**: I have tried this method on Ubuntu 13.04, and I remember using it on Ubuntu 12.10. I know very little about the possibility of using these ways in Ubuntu versions before that..

Comment: Shift+PrtSc immediately takes a screenshot of the whole desktop. I can't "click drag" to select an area.

Comment: Go to settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts(tab)>screenshots>screenshot of an area. Check if shift +PrntScr is the short cut, if not set it to be the shortcut or any other key combination. This must work, if not please report back.. I will edit my answer then to encompass the changes.

Comment: Major EDITS to my answer. hope it satisfies your needs

Comment: That is the single most awesomest thing I have learned about Ubuntu this month.

Comment: great solution, shift+imprPant worked great in my case

Comment: There is a GUI window that lets you choose some options and additional features too, if you manually launch (e.g. with Alt+F2) the program: `gnome-screenshot`

Comment: How this answer not voted as the right answer!!! This place have never failed to entertain me.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried compiz screenshot option!
Enable screenshot in your ccsm and then use Super Key (the Windows Key) + drag to get a screenshot of whatever area on desktop you like. The shots are saved on desktop (/home//Desktop) or wherever you choose when you enable the Compiz tool.

Comment: The screenshot plugin is pre-installed in compiz, you may find it in the compiz config settings manager.

Comment: I think you forgot the key to hold down while you drag.

Comment: press windows key :P, i typed *<winkey>* but it got formatted as a tag :)

Comment: Excepting that it is partially broken in Unity because it lays a blue overlay over the image captured.

Comment: @CharlesKane if it does not bother you to do one extra step, you can quickly fix the blue overlay in GIMP. Open the screenshot in GIMP, go to menu **Colors** -> **Auto** and select 'White Balance'. The problem is fixed. I used the GIMP version 2.8.

Answer (score 4):

If you use GIMP for image editing, File - Acquire - Screenshot - Select a region to grab will do the trick.

Comment: +1 For me, the menu options are `file - create - screenshot`. But, thanks!  I didn't know this trick.

Comment: Sorry about that.  The specific menu options are dependent on the version of GIMP in use.  Strange, but true!

Answer (score 3):

Alt+PrtScrn grabs just the active window.  Not exactly the box you requested, but useful if you only want to grab the app you are using.

Answer (score 2):

use Taksi...

Taksi is screen/video capture with a twist. It is designed to capture live video from your 3d based games and other 3d applications. Taksi can even perform real-time compression to popular video formats such as xvid, divx, etc - or save it uncompressed. it also takes screenshots..

Answer (score 2):

In KDE I like to use <strike>KSnapshot</strike> Spectacle ([renamed](https://kde.org/announcements/announce-applications-15.12.0.php)). It's much simpler and faster than Shutter, so it's useful in those cases where you don't need to edit anything (for which Shutter is way more powerful!).

[image]

Comment: It is called "Spectacle" now (early 2020)....and did what I needed it to.  I couldn't figure out the "save AS" function (to give the file a custom-meaningful name)...but I was still able to save-as (the "random" name it supplies).  But the "rectangle region" was the selling point for me.  Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is wondering, Spectacle is a snap app.  `sudo snap install spectacle`

Answer (score 1):

For 14.04:

- go to System Settings
- choose Keyboard button, Shortcuts tab
- choose 'Custom Shortcuts'
- click the + button
- name: 'Screenshot of selection', Command: 'gnome-screenshot -a -c'
- hit apply
- click the word 'Disabled' to change the shortcut whatever you like -- I like CTRL-SHIFT-minus

Now, I you hit the shortcut, the cursor changes to a big +. Select an area, and the screenshot is saved to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

you could "map" a key combo to do a gnome-screenshot -w to grab a window or gnome-screenshot -i for interactive options.

and of coure, PrintScreen key grabs everything. :)

Someone else may have a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flameshot, a free software available in the repository

Comment: Please provide more details.